# Version Control - webdevelopment - small team - OSX

Tags: svn, version-control, bitbucket, web-deployment, git-svn

I like to set up a ***version control*** like *Bitbucket* to develop websites in a team of 3 peolpe on OSX. (https://bitbucket.org)

**1. Currently (bad and old way):**
All users are creating there files locally and put it via ftp on the webserver.

**2. How we want to do it:**
All users create their files locally (working copy) and do a commit (easy?, fast and great!)

*Question*: Do I understand it correctly that I can set up a Bitbucket account for free (up to 5 people) and create a repository so all my users (private) can download a working copy and commit their changes easily for example like it does TortoiseSVN on Windows AND after the commit the "new" Website (working copy again?) is live?

I hope you can help me (us) - Thank you!

Comment: Learn much more about [git](http://git-scm.com/) which is used by BitBucket. All users are keeping their files locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all my users (private) can download a working copy

as long as the number of the "all users" does not exceed 5.

> like it does TortoiseSVN on Windows

bitbucket is git and doesn't support SVN AFAIU. So the "like" might be quite relative. There are easy to use GUI tools nowadays though, [SourceTree](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/sourcetree-tutorial-request-supplies-for-your-space-station-760120235.html) is one example.

> AND after the commit the "new" Website (working copy again?) is live?

No, not out of the box in a generic case. Depending on kind of the website and hosting there might be various options like [publishing a static website](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html) or integrating via the [hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html) or set something up at your hosting side.